# Retrieve string from class to my form

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to give a value in a string inside my class. Then i want using it inside my form.

Example Class:

```
public class BMI
{
  public string val = "test";
}
```

Form Example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
  BMI ss= new BMI();
  ss.val = textBox1.Text;
}
```

Unfortunately my textxbox is null. I need to be filled with value "test" from my class

Comment: So you mean `textBox1.Text = BMI.val;` instead of the other way round?

Comment: To start,it should probably be `textBox1.Text = BMI.val`.And please, don't name the instance the same as the class,that hurts my eyes

Comment: `if(textBox1.Text != "") BMI.val = textBox1.Text;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got it the wrong way round:

```
BMI BMI = new BMI();
textBox1.Text = BMI.val;
```

Comment: Thank you and sorry for my less knowledge. What if i want to send a value  to my class?

Comment: Then your original example should work - as long as you have a TextBox named textBox1 on your form

Comment: It doesnt work when i;m sending it to class.Why? BMI ss= new BMI();
ss.val = textBox1.Text; Also in class i'm using :  public string val;

Comment: Is is because your class isn't public? `public class BMI`

Comment: What makes you think it isn't working? Are there any errors?